# How to copy and paste custom emoticon

Tags: iphone, emoticons

I want to copy custom emoction from my iphone app and want to paste in anywhere in textbox inside or outside my application or i can use it in comments on instagram and facebook.I got reference app https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/emoji-for-facebook/id652079241?mt=8 that same i want to apply in my application.
can anybody help me,how do i achieve this mechanism? my custom emoticons are stored in collection view as a image.how do i copy image and paste it into comments on social networking.

Comment: This might be help you - [Does IOS support all Unicode emojies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140770/does-ios-support-all-unicode-emojies)

Comment: @TheTiger:Thank you for your reply..how to convert image to unicode emoji?

Comment: If you are talking about `UIImage to Unicode Character` then NO its not possible. I gave you link for study Mr. Jon Hanna answer and chat discussion too. He has described it please read it carefully.

Comment: @TheTiger:do you have any idea how to crate emoji as a special type of font? so i can display it into my textbox.

Comment: [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/)

Answer (score 2):

The emoticons used in text are in fact [Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons#Unicode_characters). So the "custom" emoticons are just using a special font, not images. The app you're referencing simply seems to use the same font as the Facebook app.

So the real answer is: you [copy and paste them like normal text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039224/ios-copy-and-paste). And you cannot control how they will look like in other apps, as that is dependent on the font the other app is using.

Comment: Thank you for the reply..so what should i do?..can i convert image to unicode character and paste it in textbox?

Comment: You need to create a font. How to do a colored bitmap font, I don't know.

Comment: And, as I said, you cannot influence what the emoticons will look like when you paste them into another app.

Comment: :if i convert my image to ttf font then my problem will solve?

Comment: Yes, as long as you use the correct Unicode code points for the emoticons.

Comment: :As long as unicode standard codes are defined in the unicode table so it is supported to all platforms if I create my custom emoji unicode..will it support to different platforms?

Comment: Yes, it will be supported on different platforms, that's the point of Unicode.